# MvvmCross - how to bind text to ApplicationBarMenuItem in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvmcross

I just wonder how to bind Text to my ApplicationBarMenuItem with MvvmCross.

```
<shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="{Binding TextSource,Converter={StaticResource Language},ConverterParameter=LoginCaption, FallbackValue=LoginCaption,Mode=OneTime}"/>
```

Something like that will occur a message "Error: Text cannot be empty." So I have to make that programmatically, but how exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not MVVMCross related, the problem is that the standard ApplicationBar is not bindable. I suggest you take a look at the [BindableApplicationBar](https://bindableapplicationb.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Yes thanks for this suggestion. It's working well on WP8 / WP8.1 with MvvmCross.

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind [Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx). Therefore define your TextSource property as dependency property.